# Unswipable notifications

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, notifications

On my moto G 2, in the notification area there appears to be a couple of notifications that whatever i do i can't figure out how to get rid of. One of them is an outdated voicemail reminder received weeks ago,  and it's there despite the fact that my inbox is clear.  The other is exceeded data limit. Is there any way to force the OS to clear these notifications? I have android 5.0.2

[image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click to enlarge)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the application by touching on the notification. If this doesn't help, touch and hold on the notification, this would pop up app info tab open app info and clear cache memory and  force stop the application also if you can clear the memory of the app that should definitely solve the problem (this step particularly can clear all of the data from the memory)